# Eclipse insists on adding appcompat_v7 library project and restructure my old project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have recently upgraded to the latest version of android sdk and eclipse plugin.

I noticed some big changes like it insists on adding *appcompat_v7* library folder. It added that folder to my old project when I tried to add a new activity to the project and restructured the project which caused a whole lot of errors.

**R.java** disappeared which was the main cause of errors. I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440407/appcompat-v7-and-fragment-main-xml)  but that did not satisfy my query.

As I am prevented from doing any further development as a result of these changes. Is there a way to revert back to the old way? Or some other way to continue the development. Do I have to separately create the activity files xml and java?

Comment: when you create new android application project then not click on create activity...create activity and xml file after the android application project build

Comment: I am not creating a new project. I am using an existing project and it gets restructured. Currently I am creating layout and java files separately but it would be nice if there was a way to generate activities like in the older versions. And when I try to add an activity later the restructuring takes place.